# NSDictionary to NSArray, will not display properly?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, xcode4, nsdictionary

I have a signature page, were the user can sign their name.
It needs to then be saved to NSDictionary, but i want to call a List of the keys to be text in a TableView for each row or cell.
so:

"viewImage =  saved as object to key:Random Number"

That parts somewhat easy, the hard part is when i call it on the other Page to the TableView.
It Exits the App with Error"SIGABRT". Now all my Delegates are in place and working...i believe.
now heres some example code:

FirstPage.m

```
UIImagePNGRepresentation(viewImage);
NSMutableArray *innerArray = [[NSMutableArray array]init];
[innerArray addObject:viewImage];
[SignatureSave setObject:innerArray forKey:@"5599"];
```

simple Enough, but doesnt give me an error.

SecondPage.m

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
FirstPage *appShare = (FirstPage *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSArray *dataDuplicate = [[NSArray alloc]init ];
dataDuplicate = [appShare.SignatureSave allKeysForObject:@"innerArray"];
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
NSLog(@"%@",dataDuplicate);
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if(cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero]autorelease];
}
if (dataDuplicate != nil) {
     cell.textLabel.text = [dataDuplicate objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
else
{
    UIAlertView *CellAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Error Loading content, Try Again Later." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [CellAlert show];
    [CellAlert release];
}

return cell;
}
@end
```

Now, How do i get the `viewImage` to save to the NSDictionary, to be able to call it on the `SecondPage` and display the name of the objects in the TableVIew?

Comment: Editing my answer for the third time. :-) UIImages don't necessarily have a name. What do you want to display in the table view? The name or the actual image?

Comment: i get the error on this line no matter what i put:[appDelegate.SignatureSave allValues];

Comment: I edited my answer up there. What needs to be done is to take a step back and look at what you really want to do in the table view.

Comment: FYI, NSLog sends `description` to all object arguments. So passing `[something description]` is equivalent to printing `[[something description] description]`, which is of course quite redundant.

Comment: Thanks Chuck.  I learn something new every day.

Comment: Just the name, i have a UIImageView next to the Tableview. so in the UIIMageView i want it to show the corresponding image to the key in the Tableview. Also thanks for helping me out, i can tell you understand what i'm talking about haha

Comment: Hi Keeano... you *can* display the image in a table view.  Or, you'll need to figure out a way to add the title of the image into the item you store in your dictionary (so it can be retrieved and displayed in the table).

Comment: is their a way to display the Keys in the TableView as the titles and the object(ViewImage) to display  in UIImageView?

Comment: `[[NSMutableArray array]init]` doesn't make sense. The `array` method returns an autorelease array. Use either `[[NSMutableArray alloc]init]` or `[NSMutableArray array]`.

Comment: yeah, i fixed that. i really need to just pull the Key from the dictionary to be the Tableview list, and the object being the image to be displayed in UIImageview on the right hand side of the List.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really don't understand whats your problem exactly.

first of all, **is your dictionary a retained object?**

```
//FirstPage.h

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary *SignatureSave;

//FirstPage.m

@synthesize SignatureSave;
…
UIImagePNGRepresentation(viewImage);
NSMutableArray *innerArray = [NSMutableArray array]; // using "array" is equivalent to alloc-init-autorelease
[innerArray addObject:viewImage];
[self.SignatureSave setObject:innerArray forKey:@"5599"];

// OR setting the array directly:

UIImagePNGRepresentation(viewImage);
NSArray *innerArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:viewImage];
[self.SignatureSave setObject:innerArray forKey:@"5599"];

// OR even setting the image directly to the dictionary:

UIImagePNGRepresentation(viewImage);
[self.SignatureSave setObject:viewImage forKey:@"5599"];
```

now if you access the object by writing `self.` in front it will call the retain and your object will stay alive. Otherwise it would be autoreleased at the end of the method. This will fix the problem that your dictionary is maybe not present/available at table view creation and you don't have to use a singleton.

**what are you trying to access with this code?**

```
FirstPage *appShare = (FirstPage *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

with `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]` you get your application delegate (obviously). These are the `MyAppNameAppDelegate` files but you treat it as a `FirstPage` class.
Just `NSLog()` to check you get the right class, the one you expect.

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] class]);
```

**here you have a potential leak, you alloc-init but never release it:**

```
NSArray *dataDuplicate = [[NSArray alloc]init ];
dataDuplicate = [appShare.SignatureSave allKeysForObject:@"innerArray"];
```

furthermore you can simplify it (will be autoreleased):

```
NSArray *dataDuplicate = [appShare.SignatureSave allKeysForObject:@"innerArray"];
```

and here you have another issue.
**Why do you call all keys for the object `@"innerArray"`?**

you don't have such an object and it's in many more cases wrong. `innerArray` was your previously named array in `FirstPage.m` but it is only for you as a developer to remember the variable better. After compilation it will have a cryptic name anyway. You could access your key `@"5599"` if you like but I don't think you want this. In your case you want to access all keys of the dictionary so simply call:

```
NSArray *dataDuplicate = [appShare.SignatureSave allKeys];
```

now you will have an array with all keys of your dictionary and you can access them like you do with `objectAtIndex:`.

```
NSString *keyName = [dataDuplicate objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = keyName;
id theObject = [appShare.SignatureSave objectForKey:keyName]; // for example the image
```

**Tell me if this solves your problems or tell me how I misunderstood your question.**

Answer (score -4):

I found the answer to this to be quit simple actually,

I ended up going with the Singleton Method instead of the Global Variable Method.

Now the Singleton Method looks terrifying but its quit simple, [See here.](http://iphone.galloway.me.uk/iphone-sdktutorials/singleton-classes/)

The main difference i noticed from the singleton method to the global method is,
Global method takes a lot of converting and re-converting.
Though the Singleton Method is working with a single object over many pages or classes.

Now i hope this will better assist people in the future also!

Comment: There is no significant difference in usability or functionality between a singleton and an app delegate field if you understand what you're doing.  Somehow you confused the app delegate object with one of your view controllers (close as I can tell, with the sparse source), so certainly the shared app scheme didn't work.

Comment: Well what matters is with the problem i was having, that above helped. may have been confused or gotten confused with the process but needless to say it still worked.